# Можно не занять позиции, без определения?

Tags: пунктуация

> Впрочем, разгром бездарного полководца Максенция был неминуем. Он не
>   выступил войском навстречу, не занял позиции. Не решался до
>   последнего. Дождался, пока Константин стянет свои силы. И при
>   приближении, честно скажем – *узурпатора*, вместо того чтобы
>   подготовиться к длительной осаде, а Рим было взять очень непросто, да
>   когда его защищают элитные императорские войска – преторианцы, что
>   способны к великим чудесам, к подвигам воинства, просто невозможно.

Ой, ребят, погибаю... Расставьте, пожалуйста знаки.

Досочините, что сделал Максенций "вместо того чтобы". Просто прокрастинировал, прокрастинатор нищасный...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Да, текст неясен, последнее предложение не закончено. Да и события, если судить по Википедии, описаны странно.

Так что можно только предложить реконструкцию текста в свободном изложении:

**Впрочем, разгром бездарного полководца Максенция был неминуем. Он не занял определенной позиции, не решался до последнего.  И при приближении, честно скажем – узурпатора, дождался, пока Константин стянет свои силы, вместо того чтобы подготовиться к длительной осаде. Взять же  Рим было очень непросто, а когда его защищают элитные императорские войска – преторианцы, что способны к великим чудесам, к подвигам воинства, – практически невозможно.**

Как всё это было: [см. Википедию](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%91%D0%B8%D1%82%D0%B2%D0%B0_%D1%83_%D0%9C%D1%83%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%B2%D0%B8%D0%B9%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B3%D0%BE_%D0%BC%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B0).

Comment: "Не занял определённой позиции" - это обычно в _переносном_ смысле, о нерешительности. В контексте боевых действий воспринимается так, будто полководец размышлял, то ли сдаться, то ли биться, то ли отступить. Из той статьи следует, что он готовился к боям, но плохо понимал свою задачу (готовил неэффективные обходные манёвры). Поэтому речь, скорее, идёт о том, что он не занял **боевые позиции** (видимо, здесь оборонительные), препятствуя взятию Рима.

Comment: Бедный Максенций не занял никакой позиции: ни поведенческой (оборонять город или дать сражение), ни правильного боевого расположения.. Может быть, он и бездарный, но ситуация была очень сложной. Кроме преданной гвардии, возможно, были в городе и сторонники Константина, которые называли императора трусом и настаивали на сражении. Да еще была своя магия, да еще христианский Бог, помогающий Константину.

Answer (score 3):

Собственно, о позициях.
*Он не выступил войском навстречу, не занял позиции.*

**позиция**
**2.** Место расположения войск в бою.
*Артиллерийская позиция. Выбрать место для миномётной позиции.*
**//** **обычно мн.**: позиции, -ий. Район военных действий.
*Передовые позиции. Отправиться на позиции. Сняться с позиций.*
[**Большой толковый словарь**](http://gramota.ru/slovari/dic/?word=%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%B7%D0%B8%D1%86%D0%B8%D1%8F&all=x)

*Командующий группой армий «Центр» генерал-фельдмаршал фон Клюге потребовал от своих войск не позднее 20 марта **занять позиции** и опорные пункты, благоприятные в отношении обороны, размещения и снабжения.*
*Командующему 2-й танковой армией приказывалось **удерживать позиции** на своем правом фланге и юго-западнее Сухиничи...*
[**В. Дайнес. Рокоссовский. Солдатский Маршал**](https://books.google.ee/books?id=XjK0yTTZTQkC&pg=PT347&lpg=PT347&dq=%D0%B7%D0%B0%D0%BD%D1%8F%D1%82%D1%8C%20%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%B7%D0%B8%D1%86%D0%B8%D0%B8%20%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%BC%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B4%D1%83%D1%8E%D1%89%D0%B5%D0%BC%D1%83%202-%D0%B9%20%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%B9&source=bl&ots=-O4s1H7igR&sig=eiIMC5PpTRtiE-q33tX6TilW3hs&hl=ru&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjhp-CfnJfZAhUFaVAKHXKvBRMQ6AEIJjAA#v=onepage&q=%D0%B7%D0%B0%D0%BD%D1%8F%D1%82%D1%8C%20%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%B7%D0%B8%D1%86%D0%B8%D0%B8%20%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%BC%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B4%D1%83%D1%8E%D1%89%D0%B5%D0%BC%D1%83%202-%D0%B9%20%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%B9&f=false)

Если правильно **занять** (занимать, удерживать) **позиции** [без определения], думаю, можно говорить и "не занял позиции".

Comment: "Удерживать позиции" - не тот случай; тут очевидно, что речь идет о занимаемых позициях. Клюге потребовал занять позиции, благоприятные в отношении обороны, а не просто какие-то позиции. Можно сказать "занял позиции", если из контекста ясно, о каких позициях речь.